# Do Ramsey idempotent ultrafilters exist?

Tags: set-theory, filters, ramsey-theory, idempotents

I was studying idempotent ultrafilters when I saw that no principal ultrafilter could ever be idempotent, because $\left\langle n \right\rangle \oplus \left\langle n \right\rangle = \left\langle 2n \right\rangle$.

A Ramsey ultrafilter is, by definition, never principal, so the question that arose to me was: do Ramsey idempotent ultrafilters exist?

First some explanation:

One of the characterisations of an ultrafilter to be Ramsey is:
For every partition $\{X_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ where $X_i \notin \mathcal{F}$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N} $, there exists $X \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\lvert X \cap X_i \rvert \leq 1$ for every $ i \in \mathbb{N} $.

An ultrafilter is called idempotent if $U \oplus U = U$, where
$U \oplus V = \{ A \subset \mathbb{N} \mid \{ m \in \mathbb{N} \mid A - m \in V \} \in U \}$ and $A - m = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid m + n \in A \}$

(I was trying to construct a partition of $\mathbb{N}$ of infinitely many finite pieces, such that if I get an $ A \in \mathcal{U}$ that satisfies $\lvert X \cap X_i \rvert \leq 1$ for every $ i \in \mathbb{N} $, $A$ can not be an element of $ U \oplus U$ but I did not succeed).

I have a strong feeling that a Ramsey ultrafilter cannot be idempotent, but 'a strong feeling' is not a proof. Maybe someone can help me thinking about the subject? Do there exists proofs of the form I was trying to make it? Or maybe what I want to prove is not true? Can someone recommend literature about this subject or is it just irrelevant what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ramsey ultrafilters are not idempotent.  A nice topological proof can be put together from the material in section 5 of this paper of Blass: www.math.lsa.umich.edu › ufdyn.pdf

Comment: Thanks for that! I just found the same paper yesterday. :)

Answer (score 1):

The question seems (at least to some extent) to be answered in comments, so I am posting what was said in comments as a CW-answer.

---

From the above comment by [Shawn Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/45071/shawn-henry):
Ramsey ultrafilters are not idempotent. A nice topological proof can be put together from the material in section 5 of this paper of Blass: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/ufdyn.pdf

> First since $\mathcal U+\mathcal V=\operatorname{{\mathcal U}-lim}_n (n+\mathcal V)$, while P-points are, in view of their topological description, [never limit points of a countable set of other ultrafilters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329272/why-is-a-p-point-never-the-limit-of-a-countable-set-of-non-principal-ultrafilter), it follows that no P-point can be of the form $\mathcal U+\mathcal V$ with non-principal $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal V$.  In particular, no P-point can be recurrent. So the family of P-points and, a fortiori, the subfamily of selective ultrafilters are disjoint from the families of ultrafilters studied in the preceding sections (recurrent, idempotent, etc.).