# Why is a p-point never the limit of a countable set of non-principal ultrafilters?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

There are several descriptions, but I think the following definition of **p-point** suits for now:

A point such that the intersection of countably many neighbourhoods of it, is again a neighbourhood.

In the article I'm reading (http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/ufdyn.pdf), he easily says 'p-point are, in their topological description, never the limit of a countable set of other non-principal ultrafilters'.

Can someone explain this to me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Lose I wanted to ask you, whether you would consider undeleting your question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317690/do-ramsey-idempotent-ultrafilters-exist). As the 5 upvotes suggest, the questions is interesting for other users too. It seems to be answered in the comment, so a CW-answer with the link given in the comments can be posted. (Or non-CW if you prefer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaking purely topologically, consider any T$_1$ topological space $X$, and any P-point $x \in X$.  Suppose that $\langle x_n \rangle_{n \in \omega}$ is a sequence of distinct points in $X$.  By T$_1$-ness for each $n$ there an open neighbourhood $U_n$ of $x$ which does not contain $x_n$.  But as $x$ is a P-point, then $x \in \mathrm{Int} ( \bigcap_n U_n )$, and $\bigcap_n U_n$ contains none of the points of the sequence.

This not only shows that $x$ is not a sequential limit of a non-trivial sequence in $X$, but also that $x$ is not a $\mathcal{U}$-limit (for any ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\omega$) of a non-trivial sequence in $X$.  **Even more:** a P-point is not in the closure of any countable set (the above proof actually shows this, and the others are simple corollaries to this).